# How can I give a running process priority for bandwidth usage on Windows?

Tags: windows

I found myself accidentally starting two large uploads, and since they are single BLOBs, I cannot easily stop/start them, potentially loosing much time. However, I prefer one of those processes to get the priority and give it, say, 80% of the available bandwidth.

With most file sharing tools it's relatively easy to limit or broaden the bandwidth. Is it also possible to do so for a running process? This is on Windows 7, but would equally be helpful on Windows 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at the program Net Limiter, or search for programs similar.

Here is a link to Net Limiter.

http://www.netlimiter.com/

Answer (score 2):

Instructions here: They are long so I don't think copying would make sense.
http://www.biztechmagazine.com/article/2010/03/boost-network-performance-windows-7-qos

Answer (score 1):

For a free solution check out **TMeter Freeware Edition** (http://www.tmeter.ru/en/)
whose features include:

> Traffic shaper (AKA Speed Control)